# How to display individual reports in cyrtal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I am new in using crystal reports. I already tried to create a report but it doesn't look like what I wanted. What I want to create is an individual report of each employees where it displays their information like name, age, birth date, address, etc.. But then, crystal reports will display all reports of each employees in a single document. Is there any way that I could make each employees information to display in a single document like I could use an arrow to navigate to next employee information if I want to see their report?

By the way, I used Microsoft SQL R2 in getting data for my reports. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi the question is not clear..as my  knowledge i suggest..that if you  design
the crystal report of one employee in single document and attach stored procedure to that
report your problem is solved ..you will get every employee details in a serial order this is the answer if i understand your question correctly,if not can you please repeat the questi
on with changes which i can understand
thank you